# Multiple iPhone Distribution Profiles - using Automatic Profile Selector

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, distribution, provisioning

I want to use Automatic Profile Selector.

I have my App Store Distribution Certificate and I also have my Enterprise Distribution Certificate. Both being Distribution certificates for the same app.

I have separate build configuration for each, and I choose automatic profile selector.

It is choosing the App Store certificate for both!

(yes I know I can manually select a particular certificate, but there are reasons I don't want to do this at the moment).

Am I asking too much of the automatic profile selector? Anyone have any more detailed info on how its makes its automatic certificate selection?

Thanks